# doctest fails on __main__.py

Tags: python, doctest

Doctest fails when the name of the tested file is `__main__.py`. Is this expected behaviour?

The upshot is that you then can't have any doctests in `__main__.py`. Is the workaround then to just move all doctested things out of `__main__.py` and into a different module, imported in `__main__.py`?

To reproduce: make a file whose contents are simply

```
"""
>>> 1+2
3
"""
```

Name that file anything else than `__main__.py`,

```
python -m doctest anything_but_main.py
```

and doctest passes without any problems.

Name that file `__main__.py`,

```
python -m doctest __main__.py
```

Now doctest crashes miserably:

```
**********************************************************************
File "C:\Users\PERSON\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\fle\lib\doctest.py", line 1812, in __main__.DebugRunner
Failed example:
    runner.run(test)
Expected:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    doctest.UnexpectedException: <DocTest foo from foo.py:0 (2 examples)>
Got:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\PERSON\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\fle\lib\doctest.py", line 1329, in __run
        compileflags, 1), test.globs)
      File "<doctest __main__.DebugRunner[15]>", line 1, in <module>
        runner.run(test)
      File "C:\Users\PERSON\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\fle\lib\doctest.py", line 1836, in run
        r = DocTestRunner.run(self, test, compileflags, out, False)
      File "C:\Users\PERSON\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\fle\lib\doctest.py", line 1475, in run
        return self.__run(test, compileflags, out)
      File "C:\Users\PERSON\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\fle\lib\doctest.py", line 1381, in __run
        exception)
      File "C:\Users\PERSON\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\fle\lib\doctest.py", line 1842, in report_unexpected_exception
        raise UnexpectedException(test, example, exc_info)
    UnexpectedException: <DocTest foo from foo.py:0 (2 examples)>
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of  21 in __main__.DebugRunner
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
```

Comment: I'll have to look into this more but my first guess is this has something to do with polluting the namespace. Calling `doctest` from the command line like that creates a `__name__` variable equal to  `'__main__'` so perhaps calling it as a module on a file with the same name is causing some pollution.